# Question on a "dual form" of $F$ that caprures the singularity of a plane section of $F$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In an article I was reading the notion of dual form came up, which I write down below. I was interested in learning more about this and I have two questions regarding it.

This is how it came up:
Let $F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ be a non-singular homogeneous rational polynomial. Then there exists a non-zero "dual form"
$
f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]
$
such that 
we have
$$
f(\mathbf{t}) = 0
$$
whenever the plane section 
$$
F(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{t} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 0
$$
is a singular curve. 
Furthermore, $f$ is irreducible.

My two questions are the following:

1. Does this only hold for a form in $4$ variables? or is there a generalization for which works in more variables? (so that $f(\mathbf{t})$
   vanishes whenever $F(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{t} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 0$ is singular)
2. I would like to learn some ideas behind the proof. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain me how one can obtain such a form.